# matplotlib: Axis default limits with a Circle patch

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Consider the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca()
circle = plt.Circle((0, 0), radius = 0.5)
ax.add_patch(circle)
print(plt.axis())
plt.show()
```

The default axis limits are printed as:

```
(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0)
```

I am not sure why this is the case. So, I would like to learn why?

PS: I know I can just do `plt.axis('scaled')` so that I can see the entire circle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plotting functions like `plot` or `scatter` make use of the function `autoscale_view` ([source](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/16b7958827f68d991b4bdb8899e832b167097d78/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py#L1383)). However, `add_patch` does not call it ([source](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/68176ebb3077f28627f9f1b4769cdd7135fe5535/lib/matplotlib/axes/_base.py#L1537-L1553)). 
While this explains *why* the axes are not scaled automatically in your example, I'm not sure what the underlying design choice was.

Comment: Does that answer your question? If not, what exactly is your question?

Comment: the question is "why" - the part that you are not sure about.

Comment: I see. I guess @tcaswell knows the answer

Comment: @hizg I just tried callling autoscale_view() and it fixes my issue. submitted a PR: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/3936

Comment: Please consider updating the answer with `ax.autoscale_view()` as a recipe.